# Find Maximum value and ties based on different criteria

Tags: r

For each combination of my variables `simulation` and `iteration`, I would like to

- find out whether `group "a"` had the highest value of `rand1`, as well
  as `rand2`,
- know whether `group "a"` tied with another group based on `rand1`, as well as `rand2`

Some sample df (with hard coded values for `rand1` and `rand2` for reproducibility:

```
df = crossing(simulation = 1:3,
              iteration = 1:3, 
              group =c("a","b","c")) %>%
mutate(rand1 = c(6,2,2,6,4,6, sample(6,21,replace=T)), # roundabout way to get the same head of df as in the example, forgot to use set.seed
       rand2 = c(4,1,2,5,6,1,sample(6,21,replace=T)))
```

which gives:

```
 simulation iteration group    rand1 rand2
          1         1 a            6     4
          1         1 b            2     1
          1         1 c            2     2
          1         2 a            6     5
          1         2 b            4     6
          1         2 c            6     1
```

This is what I want my output to look like: `top.crit1` is 1 if group a is max, 0 if there is  a tie. `ties.crit1` lets me know if a was tied for max value with another group, same for `top.crit2` and `ties.crit2` [not added below to avoid cluttering]
Desired output:

```
 simulation iteration group    rand1 rand2  top.crit1 ties.crit1 
          1         1 a            6     4  1         0
          1         1 b            2     1  1         0
          1         1 c            2     2  1         0
          1         2 a            6     5  0         1
          1         2 b            4     6  0         1
          1         2 c            6     1  0         1
```

This is my code so far for only determining the max value (but doesn't take into account ties), it's a bit tedious to determine the maximum value separately for `rand1` and `rand2`.

```
  df.test = df %>%
  group_by(simulation, iteration) %>% 
  slice(which.max(rand1)) %>% 
  mutate(top.crit1 = if_else(group=="a",1,0)) %>% 
  select(-rand2, -rand1, -group) %>% 
  full_join(., df)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? Since you don't provide a `set.seed` value, it's impossible for us to reproduce your `df` data frame as you show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you `arrange` to have group a as first row of each group

`df %>%
  group_by(simulation, iteration) %>% 
  mutate(top.crit1 = rand1[1] > max(rand1[-1])) %>%
  mutate(ties.crit1 = rand1[1] == max(rand1[-1]))`